# Lock openfile dialog to initialDirectory and not browse other folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openfiledialog

How do I in C# 'lock' the openfile dialog to only accept to browse from the default location and not any other location. In the code below one can browse any location.I want the user to only browse C:\Users\Public\Pictures and nowhere else. Does anyone know how?

```
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.FileName = ".jpg";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible using the OpenFileDialog.  You may have to create your own dialog using the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control (or something similar)